# Code signing macOS app with Electron

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I cannot seem to get code signing to work with electron-builder. When I run `security find-identity -v` I get back 3 certs, all of which look good. They also show up when running electron-builder. However, it says that `cannot find valid "Developer ID Application" identity or custom non-Apple code signing certificate` and directs me to the electron-builder docs (which are not helpful at all).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: not much helpful but have you tried to sign via `electron-osx-sign` directly? we've ended up to sign pkg separately instead of relying on packager's process for reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Before running electron builder, set the environment variables like this -

```
export DEBUG=electron-builder
export CSC_LINK=~/Desktop/mac_certs.p12 (change path according to your location)
export CSC_KEY_PASSWORD={your cert password}
```

Then try running with electron builder.
If this does not work, please paste the output of electron-builder

Comment: Dumb question, but where do I find the `.p12` file? The certs were generated by apple.

Comment: Also, according to docs, shouldn't the build process locate the file automatically? Either way, I'll definitely give this a shot.

Comment: @NickParsons Export those certs from the keychain to a p12 format

Comment: Okay, did all that. Long error message with nothing meaningful to post aside from the fact that it's not picking up the path to the `.p12` file.

Comment: @Ajey How do you export the certs to a `.p12` file when they generated by Apple and downloaded through their website? When I try to do so through Keychain Access, the option is disabled.